# Is there a particular name for this kind of "poster"? Is this called a poster?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, word-usage

I was talking to a friend and wanted to speak about a particular kind of "poster" that has small hanging strips of paper containing information about services, sellers, or in this case the cat owner:

[image: Image of the poster]

What do you call this? Is this even called a poster? And what about the strips of paper? What do you call them in English?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that is a poster.  I would call it a *poster with tear-off tabs*.  I think Microsoft Word even has a template for this type of poster.

Update:  Microsoft does offer a Word template and calls it a *poster with tear-off tabs*.

Comment: I dunno: if it's a simple piece of paper (like this is), I'd still call it a *flyer*. *Poster* implies something larger, more colorful, and probably with a glossy finish.

Comment: Microsoft also offers templates for *flyers* with tear-off tabs.

Comment: Wow. Validated by Microsoft. Next step down from [The Academy](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/academy.html)

Comment: @Marthaª: I think a _flyer_ has to be mobile somehow, though this is the right size and shape for a flyer; this one, however, won't work unless it's _posted_ somewhere. I grant you this is not a [prototype](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAPrototype.htm) _poster_, which is as you describe it; but it has to be posted and it can't fly, so that feels like a different category to me.

Comment: *Flyer* connotes something you would distribute by hand or stick under people's windshield wipers.

Answer (score 14):

I'd call it a *flyer with pull tabs*. The more common phrase is *flyer with tear-off tabs*, perhaps because another type of "pull tab" can be used to open a can. In this case, though, "pull tab" has its origins in gambling, where you'd pull a tab on a ticket to reveal if you had won a prize.

It's worth noting that flyer can also be spelled *flier*.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a flyer. Flyer implies something handed out, like a leaflet. If it's stuck up like that, it's a poster. After all, it's posted on the wall/pole/board/whatever.

Comment: For me, the difference between poster and flyer lies in the size, not in the use. For example, a "poster tube" is a package for shipping posters, and those are for a much larger size of poster than could fit on a utility pole. Also, just because it's posted and not handed out that doesn't mean the name has to fit. All those signs on walls in large cities that say "post no bills" are referring, in short form, to handbills or advertisements that might be tacked up or pasted onto their walls.

Comment: The [Free Dictionary, here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flyer) defines a flyer (in this context) to be _a small handbill_, which it [then goes on to define](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/handbill) as _a printed sheet or pamphlet distributed by hand_, which the illustration assuredly is not. So I have to say, I don't think this is a _flyer_.

Comment: Playing devil's advocate against my own answer here, cf. *wanted poster.*

Answer (score 5):

It can also be referred to as a notice, specifically a lost and found notice. If the subject was commercial in nature, it would be an advertisement.

Answer (score 4):

It's definitely a poster.

As for the tear-off bits, if they are not actually referred to as *tear-off bits* or *strips* then *tabs* or maybe *tags* would do. But you would probably end up having to explain what you meant.

Answer (score 3):

A notice that is tacked up on telephone polls and walls is sometimes called a "broadsheet". That word doesn't imply anything about pull-off tabs though.